# ActionView::MissingTemplate when using Rails.ajax and jquery sortable plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I followed [this episode](https://gorails.com/episodes/sortable-drag-and-drop) on Go Rails to add the jquery ui sortable plugin to my app (basically to add drag and drop functionality).

Everything works until the ajax request. Even then, it starts the `patch` request, but never even gets to the controller action (no changes are made on the database and a `binding.pry` that I put at the top of the action doesn't get triggered).

This is the error that I get:

```
Started PATCH "/contents/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-27 17:03:43 +0530
Processing by ContentsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"content"=>["13", "4"]}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template contents/sort, 
application/sort with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], 
:variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, 
:coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/mnt/c/Users/mumar/Documents/Code/Frontier/newsletter-app/app/views"
  * "/home/Umar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/views"
):
```

Here's the extract from my **CoffeeScript file**:

```
document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('.sortable').sortable 
    handle: '.handle'
    update: (e, ui) ->
      Rails.ajax
        url: $(this).data("url")
        type: "PATCH"
        data: $(this).sortable 'serialize'
      return
  return
```

Here's the **controller action**:

```
def sort
  binding.pry
  params[:content].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Content.where(id: id).update_all(position: index + 1)
  end

  head :ok
end
```

The **views** are spread across different partials, I've just included the relevant bits here:

Main `.sortable` div:

```
<div class="sortable list-group" data-url="<%= sort_contents_path %>">
  <% section.contents.each do |content| %>
    <% if (content.edition == @edition) && (content.top_story == false) %>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/content', locals: {content: content} %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The `shared/content` partial from the above snippet:

```
<div class="card-content list-group-item" id="<%= dom_id(content) %>">
  <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
    <%= content.heading %> 

    <%= link_to fa_icon('star', 'aria-hidden': 'true', 
      style:top_story_status_color(content)), toggle_top_content_path(content), 
      set_tooltip('Top Story') %>

    <span class="handle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Move Article">
      <%= fa_icon('arrows', 'aria-hidden': 'true', style: 'color: #a1a1a3;') %>      
    </span>
    </h5>
  <p class="card-text"><%= content.body %></p>
  <span>
    Read More: <%= link_to content.link, content.link, class: "content-link" %>  
  </span>
</div>
```

To be clear, I can drag and drop content, I just can't make the new positions persist in the database. I get the above error whenever I drag anything (though my application keeps working - the error is only on the console, not the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not sure what happened, but it seems to have fixed itself.

Quite strange, given that I had restarted my rails servers several times when testing this and had even shut down my PC and tried it again the next day with no luck.

It just works now and I'm very confused. Either way, I think I can close this question.